Extract a word between two characters, end character can be two different
I want to find a word between two characters, but the end character can be two different.
*) or |
The text I want is "special text" (that text line can bee diffrent)
the string can look like this:
a lot of text (special text|more text)
but also
a lot of text (special text)
line = "a lot of text (*special text |more text*)"

substring = line[line.index('*')+1:line.index('|')]
print(substring)


Instead of using index, you should use a regular expression. For example, you could search for text between (* and *) and then split that by |. Note that *, ( and ) are special characters in regex and need to be escaped.
>>> import re
>>> line = "a lot of text (*special text |more text*) bla (*even more | special | text*)"
>>> re.findall(r"\(\*(.*?)\*\)", line)
['special text |more text', 'even more | special | text']
>>> [y.strip() for x in re.findall(r"\(\*(.*?)\*\)", line) for y in x.split("|")]
['special text', 'more text', 'even more', 'special', 'text']

